# Looking for a hex editor that can find specific binary sequence unaligned

Tags: gratis, search, hex-viewer, reverse-engineering, binary-data

I am looking for a Hex Editor that can do a search for a specific binary sequence, and find it in a file, without regard to byte alignment. I have an extracted and disassembled program that I am reverse engineering for personal use, and it contains a file that is made using a combination of field encoding (such as `Charset:ANSI;UseInternalFont:1;iFontData:(BinaryData)` (**see note 1 at bottom for what the 'BinaryData' is**), for example) and bit encoding where the bitwidth varies depending on the data that is encoded (for example, flags, depending on what they are for, can use anywhere from 1 to 4 bits). The following features are required:

1. Program is free (ad-supported is okay as well)
2. Program has a Binary View
3. Program supports searching for Binary Data and
4. Said search can find binary sequences independent of alignment

Example:
I have a string of binary data as follows:

```
0010 1001 0111 1010 1000 1011 0100 0101 0110
```

Searching for '010010', it finds one result:

```
001|->|0 1001 0|<-|111 1010 1000 1011 0100 0101 0110
```

Is there such a software out there, either online or installable, for free?

Note 1: The 'BinaryData' mentioned above is a specific where each graphical representation of a character in a font is stored as a 526-bit stream, where 512 bits are the character itself (each bit is a pixel, where a 0 is white, and a 1 is black), and the other 14 bits are data for things such as how many pixels wide the character is, the positioning of the character in the font table (the final font is actually a raw image with all 95 printable ASCII characters spaced evenly, and this data tells where each character is placed within it when creating the font internally), and other things; the font is extracted and saved as a font.bin file in a random folder name within the PC's "%LOCALAPPDATA\Temp\" folder at program runtime if it doesn't exist yet.